# Is it possible to derive the Logistic model growth like exponential growth model?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

Is it possible to derive the Logistic model growth like exponential growth model?

**Exponential growth equation derivation.**

Let $P(t)$ denote the population of a city at time $t$ years. $P(t+\Delta t)$ denote the population of a city at time $t+\Delta t$ years. $b$ denote the total number of birth per individual per year. $d$ denote the total number of death  per individual per year.
$$P(t+\Delta t)=P(t)+(b-d)P(t)\Delta t$$

$$\frac{P(t+\Delta t)-P(t)}{\Delta t}=(b-d)P(t)$$

As $\Delta t \to 0,$ We get $\frac{dP(t)}{dt}=(b-d)P(t).$ Similarly how to derive the logistic model of growth?

> $$\frac{dP}{dt}=cP(P-K)/K$$

Comment: You might like my video on deriving these equations. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NRm4xngylwo&list=PL2Ky2_VcYEd1-UmZxmNXaQh2AjKY8tpvI&index=7

Comment: Perhaps this is why you're looking for: https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.571.3727&rep=rep1&type=pdf